# Changing size of NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I am trying to implement an `NSTextView` which resizes to fit its content. I am trying to make it so it has a maximum amount of lines. Meaning, that when this limit is reached, it will not grow any further and  the user will be able to scroll it.

There seem to be a lot of people wanting this but I have not found a complete implementation of this.

The idea is to take the content size of the `NSTextView` and resize it so that it matches. I just can't figure out how to set the layout size of the `NSTextView`. It does not seem to be it's `frame` which needs to be set and which one might expect.

Can anyone please tell me how to set the frame of the `NSTextView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that it's the height of the scroll view which should be changed. Changing the height of an `NSTextView` can be done by overwriting the `-didChangeText` method like below.

```
- (void)didChangeText
{
    NSScrollView *scrollView = (NSScrollView *) self.superview.superview;
    NSRect frame = scrollView.frame;

    // Calculate height
    NSUInteger numberOfLines = [self numberOfLines];
    NSUInteger height = frame.size.height;
    if (numberOfLines <= 13)
    {
        height = 22 + (numberOfLines - 1) * 14;
        if (height < 22)
            height = 22;
    }

    // Update height
    frame.size.height = height;
    self.superview.superview.frame = frame;
}
```

Play around with the constants to get the result you wish for.