# Using Wrapping Text Field in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield, nstextfield

Can we have a multiline text field in **SwiftUI**?  I'm talking about something equivalent to Wrapping Text Field that is available for **Cocoa**.  I hear that you can use `TextEditor`, an equivalent of `NSTextView` under macOS 11 and `UITextView` under iOS 14.  No, that's not what I'm talking about.  I'm talking about the `NSTextField` with Word Wrap as the line break.

[image]

```
struct EventView: View {
    @State var eventName: String = ""
    @State var eventSum: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 18)
            
            HStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(width: 16)
                        Text("Name: ")
                        TextField("", text: $eventName)
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(width: 16)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 10)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(width: 16)
                        Text("Summary: ")
                        TextField("", text: $eventSum)
                            .frame(height: 48.0)
                            .lineLimit(4)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(width: 16)
                    }
                    /*
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 10)
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(width: 16)
                        Text("Time: ")
                        
                    }
                    */
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: 80.0)
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 20.0)
                Button("Save") {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: 80.0)
            }
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 18)
        }
        .frame(width: 240, height: 180)
    }
}
```

If I run the code above, I only get a regular text field, which is equivalent to `NSTextField` with Clip as the line break.  If I set the height to 48 points, it's been ignored.  In case you need to know, my develoyment target is macOS 15, The Xcode version is 12.2.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63144255/12299030? (possible duplicate)

Comment: Thanks, @Asperi.  I'll take a close look at it after eating dinner.  I'm not talking about `NSTextView` or `UITextView`, though.