# Can I Stop NSViewRepresentable layout lag for NSTextView?

Tags: swiftui, nstextview, nsviewrepresentable

I am using an `NSTextView` inside `NSViewRepresentable` in a SwiftUI app.

The `NSViewRepresentable` correctly resizes to the height of the NSTextView, so the text flows to multiple lines, **but on the first render after creation it only shows a single line**.

It appears that the `NSTextView` is rendered correctly on this first frame, with the text wrapped at the right point, but the `NSViewRepresentable` is not displaying the full height.

The `NSTextView` is created, and the text set on `NSTextStorage` in the `makeCoordinator()` method of `NSViewRepresentable`, i.e. before `NSViewRepresentable` requests the view.

I override `NSTextView` to set the `intrinsicContentSize`:

```
    override func layout() {
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        super.layout()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
            layoutManager!.ensureLayout(for: textContainer!)
            return CGSize(width: -1.0,
                          height: ceil(layoutManager!.usedRect(for: textContainer!).size.height))
    }
```

I think this issue was hinted at by the 'bobble' mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63144255/978300). The height tracking method is different but also fails to set the first frame.

Is there anything I can do to force layout sooner on the `NSTextView`? The view is not fixed width so it needs to flow dynamically.

Here is a minimal reproduction:

```
import SwiftUI

    let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
    let testString = "This long string demonstrates how its full extent is not shown on the first frame of an NSTextView rendered within an NSViewRepresentable."
    let fontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
    let testText = NSAttributedString(string: testString, attributes: fontAttribute)
    
    class InternalTextView: NSTextView
    {
        init() {
            super.init(frame: NSRect.zero)
            setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        }
        
        override init(frame frameRect: NSRect, textContainer container: NSTextContainer?) {
            super.init(frame: frameRect, textContainer: container) }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

        override func layout() {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            super.layout()
        }
            
        override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
            layoutManager!.ensureLayout(for: textContainer!)
            return CGSize(width: -1.0,
                          height: ceil(layoutManager!.usedRect(for: textContainer!).size.height))
        }
    }
    
    
    class TextViewCoordinator: NSObject {
        private(set) var view: InternalTextView
        
        init(withText text: NSAttributedString) {
            view = InternalTextView()
            view.textStorage?.setAttributedString(text)
            super.init()
        }
    }
    
    struct TextView: NSViewRepresentable
    {
        let text: NSAttributedString
        
        func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextView { context.coordinator.view }
        
        func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextView, context: Context) { }
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> TextViewCoordinator { TextViewCoordinator(withText: text) }
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View
    {
        let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        @State var showText: Bool = false
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        if showText {
                            ForEach(1..<10) { _ in
                                TextView(text: testText)
                            } }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }.frame(maxWidth: 600)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                showText.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
```

Frame 1:

[image: The first rendered frame]

Frame 2:

[image: The second rendered frame]

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out yet? I have the same issue, and when this sort of problem happens inside a scrollview, it's even worse.

Comment: It’s a bug in NSTextview I’m afraid. I opened a technical support issue with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I had a **very similar problem** with a ViewRepresentable on iOS where I was using CoreText to do some things with text rendering.  The symptoms were nearly identical.

The solution in my case was to a override **sizeThatFits()** on ViewRepresentable and give it the proper information (calculating text height for frame in layout) in the source view.

```
func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, uiView: <YOUR VIEW>, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
        
        return uiView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: proposal.width ?? 0, height: proposal.height ?? 0))
    }
```

I am not sure if this will work for your exact situation, but I spent a good week or so pulling my hair out on the same thing so I thought I would share.

Comment: Do you mean manually calculating the text size with something like this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1478566-ctframesettersuggestframesizewit

Comment: No, just merely implementing that method in that manner (again on iOS as stated) resolved this for me.

Comment: Just redirecting sizeThatFits didn't work for me, I had to calculate the size using CoreText, then it worked perfectly.